# How migrate PostgreSQL database from virtual machine to production server?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

i tried to migrate database from virtual machine to production server (both working on Ubuntu)
but i faced a lot of problems first when i tired to create backup file with that command

```
pg_dump mydb --file=db.dump --host=localhost --username=admin
```

this errors show up

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for schema topology
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE topology.topology IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

then i tried this command and it goes well

```
pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump
```

and when i tried to restore db to production server i used this command(after creating an user and a database with that user)

```
psql -d mydb --file=db.dump
```

this error show up

```
The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database.
```

Then I use this command to restore it

```
pg_restore -d mydb db.dump
```

and it go well but when I run the server using this command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

This error shows up

```
return value.replace(b'\0', b'').decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a superuser. Apparently "admin" is not a superuser.

Your first attempt is creating a plain-text backup, which you can restore using "psql". Your second attempt ("-Fc") creates a custom format backup, and you need "pg_restore" to restore it.

And don't forget to migrate the global objects (roles, tablespaces ect), using "pg_dumpall -g".